# GPU issues w/Claymore dual miner (eth/sia)

Tags: mining, gpu, claymore, rig

Wondering if anyone can help me please...

Been running stable for some time on 9.5 (6x Strixx ROG 8GB OC GPU's) running around 27.8M/H each dual mining Eth and Sia.

I tried v9.6 and used the following when running Claymore: -cclock 1000 -mclock 1850 -cvddc 850

Shortly after starting it, my rig crashed and struggled to come back to life. Best I've been able to do is have any 2 of the GPU's connected at once for it to work.

Starting Claymore without (-cclock 1000 -mclock 1850 -cvddc 850) seems to be resulting in both GPU's running at around 29M/H. Connecting anymore than 2 GPU's and my rig is unstable, either Win10 doesn't load properly (graphics look knackered - can only see mouse pointer on black screen) or Claymore crashes.

It seems like using -cclock 1000 -mclock 1850 -cvddc 850 to run Claymore once has saved settings on the cards that they don't like? is that even possible? If not, why would the rig not reboot fine with all 6 GPU's connected, surely it should be the same as before? or why are the 2 GPU's running at a higher M/H when I'm running Claymore as I did before using those switches.

Has anyone experienced this before?

Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Cheers

Comment: Can you PLEASE share you eth+sia BAT file ?

Comment: BAT file contents as follows:

setx GPU_FORCE_64BIT_PTR 0
setx GPU_MAX_HEAP_SIZE 100
setx GPU_USE_SYNC_OBJECTS 1
setx GPU_MAX_ALLOC_PERCENT 100
setx GPU_SINGLE_ALLOC_PERCENT 100

EthDcrMiner64.exe -mode 0 -epool eu1.ethermine.org:4444 -ewal XXXXX.RIG1 -epsw x -dpool stratum+tcp://sia-eu1.nanopool.org:7777 -dwal XXXXX dcoin sia -dcri 5 -mport 0

Comment: I use 1x rx480 and 1x rx570 on ethos. Until recently i had only the 480 working. Now, i combine both of them and the system bootup into ethos. When minong starts i get a black screen and the system stops completely. I have bios modded rx480 and an 650w old psu

Answer (score 0):

Got everything back up and running. It was an odd one...issues were...

a) the first pci slot on the mobo...anytime anything was plugged in to that there were all kinds of weird graphic behaviour on screen

b) the mobo part of a single usb riser...although it doesn't appear to be faulty (issue only arose when all 6 gpus were plugged in), swapping it out for a spare/new one I had seemed to allow all 6 to work again

Not sure if unrelated (the pci slot dying) but that was the root cause of the instability.